# how to get data from ResponseEntity when request is success in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot

So, I have my spring-boot controller and ajax function to get response data, after I get response in my ajax success, but the data is undefined, however the HTTP status is 204, which is good, but why the data is undefined and how to get it in my ajax to access the property in my object that I want to get?

## My controller

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/**/delete/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    Optional<Offer> optional = this.offerRepository.findById(id);
    if (optional.isPresent()) {
        this.offerRepository.deleteById(id);
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        Offer offer = optional.get();
        return new ResponseEntity<Offer>(offer, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    } else {
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
        String msg = "Offer is not found";
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(msg, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

## My ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/" + currentUserRoleName + '/delete' + "/" + offerIdValue,
    scriptCharset: 'UTF-8',
    method: 'DELETE',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data); // get undefine
        console.log(jqXHR.status); //status is 204
        var offer = $.parseJSON(data.responseText); //here error call of undefine
        if (jqXHR.status === 204 || jqXHR.status === 200) {
            // var id = offer.id;
            var selector = "input#offerHiddenId[value =  '" + offerIdValue + " ']";
            var hiddenInputWithOfferId = $(".main_out_wrapper_user_offers").css(selector);
            var parent = hiddenInputWithOfferId.closest("div.inner_main_out_wrapper_user_offers");
            parent.empty();
            $("#no").click();
        } else {
            alert("Can't delete the offer");
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert(data.responseText);
        var div = $.createElement("div");
        var span = $.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = "Offer is not found";
        div.appendChild(span);
        div.fadeIn(1000, function () {
            div.fadeOut(1000);
        });
    }
});
```

## Librery for spring-boot to convert an object to JSON format in pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <jaction.xml.version>2.9.6</jaction.xml.version>
</properties>

    <!--FOR JSON-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jaction.xml.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jaction.xml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried to delete the offer from the database and I send the request from my page and the offer was deleted from database, however with the response is not so good, when I send the new ResponseEntity(msg, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) I still get the undefined data in my ajax function.

I want to get the Offer object in JSON format in ajax to access the id from offer object.

Comment: Show us the `Offer` class too

Comment: Under if condition the HttpStatus is NO_CONTENT and the else has NOT_FOUND , why so ?